# How to concatenate some read-only text at the end of the text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield, input-field

How to make only some text in a text-box read-only while allowing the rest to be edited. I'm trying to make a text box that allow user to input text and then there is some read-only text (non-editable) at the end of the text box. How can I do this in Javascript/jquery?

Eg of an input field:

**DELIVERY ADDRESS**

*Enter your home or apartment number*, **ABC Area, XYZ Town**

In above eg user is asked to provide home or apartment number and **ABC Area, XYZ Town** is a predefined value (already provided at some stage). If I split them in 2, most user put their complete address in the text field resulting in duplication of data. I  need to avoid this duplication.

Thanks a mill in advance for your help.

Comment: This isn't possible in the manner you describe. The value of the textbox is either editable or not, you cannot have a partial mix. A solution would be to have two boxes, one editable for the user, and the other readonly with the value you require.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't possible solution for you to do for such case.

For better user experiences, I would suggest you to put editable text in a text box, and non-editable words in labels. In will help to not make user confuses.

Answer (score 0):

I would do in the following way. 
I would create two text boxes:
- text_box_1 - **ABC Area** and  
- text_box_2 - **XYZ Town** //but invisible (style="display:hidden")
the content of **text_box_2** by using jQuery I would populate an Absolute element with position above the **text_box_1** which would look inside of **text_box_1** but it will not affect the editable content. 
If makes sense, you can follow such approach.